# ServerCount variable returning 0 instead of 2

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, guilds = True, reactions = True, members = True, presences = True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix, intents = intents)
serverCount = str(len(client.guilds))
status = cycle([f'Verified in {serverCount} servers!', ';help'])

@tasks.loop(seconds=15)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=next(status)))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Galactia is prepared for lift off!')
    change_status.start()
```

serverCount is meant to return 2 because the bot is in 2 servers but instead it returns 0 or an empty list. It works completely fine with no errors but it still returns 0

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're setting the value of `serverCount` before the bot has actually logged in. Therefore the value of `len(client.guilds)` is 0.
To fix this, you'll need to set the value in the `on_ready` event.

```
serverCount = ""

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Galactia is prepared for lift off!')
    serverCount = str(len(client.guilds))
    change_status.start()
```